# Soap message request not working when "&" as string in one of the elements, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, nsurlsession

I am trying to send a soap message using NSURLsession. 
-(NSString *)createSoapMessage{

```
self.soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                  "<soap:Body>"
                  "<F2 xmlns=\"website address\">"
                  "<a>%@</a>"
                  "<b>%@</b>"
                  "<c>U(GHB&@DG)</c>"
                  "</F2>"
                  "</soap:Body>"
                  "</soap:Envelope>",@"username",@"password"];
NSLog(@"%@", _soapMessage);
return self.soapMessage;}
```

Then using NSMutableURLRequest i build the request and pass it as POST using NSURLSession.

However i am not getting any response when i have "&" as part of string which is passed in U(GHB&@DG). 
o/P is 
    "DONE. Received Bytes: 0"

However when i pass any other string which does not has "&", everything works fine.

U(GHB@DG) gives me an output    DONE. Received Bytes: 333

I am new to objective C, Am i missing something.

My colleague is using same thing in Android ,and he is getting response correctly with "&" also, so i do not thing its problem on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are generating the request, you are responsible for properly encoding the XML data such that the special characters like & and < are not as a part of the data for your XML to be parsed properly at the server.

So you can either use `CDATA` tag in your value of the XML tag -

```
<![CDATA[
   U(GHB&@DG)
 ]]>
```

Or you can replace all the occurrence of '&' with `&amp;` or `&#38;` You can do this manually using String method by replacing occurence or try encoding the string before passing.

The complete list of special characters in XML are mentioned [here](https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html#gsc.tab=0)